# How to create a django microservices monorepo?

Tags: python, django, microservices, monorepo

Given this `blog` project which has `posts` and `comments` apps:

```
blog
├── blog
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── comments
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
├── manage.py
└── posts
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── migrations
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── tests.py
    └── views.py
```

I want to be able to run each of the apps (services) independently. The `django-admin runserver` runs the whole app which is not what my intention. I want to run and deploy services independently, each with its own db and port, and choose which services to start in advance. I'm aware that each app can have its own db specified in settings.py. Not sure about how to run services independently though. I also want the resulting project structure to be PyCharm-friendly, which means I can choose which services to run within the same project workspace.